# How to start apache server locally?

Tags: apache

I installed apache server on my computer...
I want to simulate how the server works in order to test my code.

After instllation when I run it, i got this message:
[image]

I couldn't find what cause this problem.

**EDIT**: this is what I see...
[image]

How do I srart the server? How do I "upload" my code to it?

Comment: (as you're really trying to get Django set up and run your code under it)  Django will run under apache, you've got to set up some modules :  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have something using port 80.

1) Start the prompt

Start menu -> Run -> Type `cmd.exe` 
or 
"Windows button" + R -> Type `cmd.exe` .
or

2) Follow instructions below

```
netstat -ano
```

Example result (my OS is Swedish so I translated the headings so it might not match 100%):

```
Active connections

  Proto  Local address          Remote address         Status          PID
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       932
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    0.0.0.0:623            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       7896
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3389           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1384
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5357           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    0.0.0.0:7779           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    0.0.0.0:7800           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
```

And check the list to see if you have another server running.

The last column is the PID. Check it in task manager or any other way you like.

Comment: In apache monitor I have under "service status" a green sun 'apache 2', is that means its on? How do I upload my code to it?

Comment: yep, that would indicate it's running. your httpd.conf file will contain a 'DocumentRoot' setting. that's the root directory for your public html files etc.

Comment: If you surf to http://localhost/ you'll see if you have apache running! In that case you need to find its directory and put your files there.

Comment: DId what you said... my appache server is on state listneing.  I guess it's mean the server is up. How do I upload the code files to it?

Comment: as I mentioned, you're probably worth checking the httpd.conf file  BUT, if I'm not mistaken the default install directory is C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\htdocs\   - thats where you need to 'upload' your files.  ( as your running the server locally you don't 'upload' anything, you just copy them to the folder)

Comment: I copied my whole project there... but it doesn't load. the 'localhost' shows me apache welcome screen.. but my project doesn't. should I do something speciel to the server so it can run it? my project is django.

Comment: I guess my question is.. normaly when uploading code file to the server.. the server should compile them. How do I make it compile my code?

Comment: ok, your question is a bit bigger than just get apache running really.  I suggest creating a new question.  but you'll need to set up python and django etc..  Apache is just a web server, it's not going to 'compile' those for you.  (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/windows/)

Answer (score 0):

First stop the Apache server, then start it again. It looks like you already started the server, and again try to start